# Compare values in two differents excel files?

Tags: python, excel

I am writing in python a programme that finds the sex of an user given the messages that he/she wrote on reddit. At the end of the programme I have two different files:

[image]

with 15000 rows and at the same row there is not the same author.

Do you know how can I compare them?

I should put at the same row the same author but I have some problems with 'for' due to dimension of files.

Thanks

Comment: So you want the second excel file to have the same order of "Author" as the first excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these are csv's this will sort both files.

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.read_csv('firstFile.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('secondFile.csv')

df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['author,gender'], ascending=True)
df2 = df1.sort_values(by=['author,gender'], ascending=True)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, and do you know how can I compare them, because I have always some difficulties with csv. I can't manage them as a matrix, but I can create a dictionary correct?

Comment: If you want to use a matrix you can create a numpy array using df.to_numpy() otherwise yes you can use df.to_dict() to get a dictionary result. More info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html